# Elasticsearch List Indices Using Boolean Query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have elastic cluster with hundreds of indices. Is there any way to list (search) indices using boolean query? e.g.

```
( index.alias:*read_index* AND doc.count:<1000 ) OR ( index.name* ) OR (index.size:<2gb) OR (index.replica:>2)
```

I need to filter out required indices from the list of hundreds of indices.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Don't think this is possible unless you create a new index containing this information and searching that.

Comment: Using a clever mix of the [`_cat` APIs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html) + `jq` + `awk` you should be able to achieve what you want.

Comment: What is jq and awk?

Comment: @MohammadShahid are you using [X-Pack Monitoring](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/es-monitoring.html)? If so, it would be easy to run that query on the `.monitoring` indices that do keep info about the monitored indices.

Comment: @AndreiStefan I am making a gui tool to manage elasticsearch indices.

Comment: Well, I asked something else :-).

Answer (score 2):

Using plain elasticsearch bool queries :), just store the JSON format [cat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat.html) output into an index, then make the queries you need, automatize the collection with a cronjob to gather this every X time, my python script looks like this:

```
# install dependencies: pip install requests
import requests
import json

ES_URL = "http://localhost:9200"

res = requests.get("{}{}".format(ES_URL, "/_cat/indices"),
                   params={"format": "json", "bytes": "m"})

for index_info in res.json():
    index_url = "{}/{}/{}/{}".format(
        ES_URL, "cat_to_index", "doc", index_info["index"]
    )

    requests.post(
        index_url,
        data=json.dumps(index_info),
        headers={'Content-type': 'application/json'}
    )

# ready to query http://localhost:9200/cat_to_index/_search
# ready to keep up-to-date with a cronjob, as the index name is the ID new values will be overwritten.
```

hope it helps.

Comment: This is not realtime, I will have to index data first before using it. In my case, I have to hit the search API every second and data must be correct every time (e.g. doc count etc)

Comment: is not possible directly with `cat` API, the only option you have is to use the `res = requests.get` line and make an in-memory search directly from the script.

Comment: this is not the only option, the other one by @AndreiStefan is also viable, i.e. use XPack Monitoring and query the `.monitoring` indices.